# Multimedia email key doesn't work in KDE

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde

My laptop keyboard have two multimedia keys: email and www. Key to open www browser works and has no problem, but email key after it has pressed doesn't open email client. When I configure this shortcut in Systemsetting after I press this key it is normally recognized, but it email client no started.